# Git CLI not found on your PATH. It must be installed to connect this app to Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

While I'm creating myApp and running this command:

```
ionic start myApp tabs
```

in cmd prompt, I'm getting this error:

> [ERROR] Git CLI not found on your PATH. It must be installed to connect this app to Ionic.

Comment: It's telling you that you need to install the Git CLI.

Comment: How can we check  if GIT is installed or not in command prompt @AndrewMorton.Becuase GIT is already  installed in my machine

Comment: Enter `PATH`. You should see "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd" (or perhaps the equivalent for your computer's UI language) somewhere in there. If not, [Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9546324/1115360).

Comment: I do not have git in the above path(C:\Program Files\Git\cmd") , i have in C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe ,I have added this path  but still  same issue .can you please help  me @AndrewMorton

Comment: I suggest that you remove that path and re-install from [Git downloads](https://git-scm.com/downloads).

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all solution which all wrote in this page. But did not work on my system. So I tried add as environment variable to -->
"**C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe**" and then it is worked.

If someone still looking for it you can try it.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install Git. In my case, Git 2.14 did the magic.
And create a new project

Comment: I installed Git after getting this error however it was not added to my path. Then I realized that I needed to close my old dos window and start a new one.

Comment: I am having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and to fix it you should follow these steps:

1. Close windows cmd window.
2. Download git here: [Git Official Website](https://git-scm.com/)
3. Choose this option on installation : [Setup Option Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf96r.png)
4. Complete Git installation.

Now you can start ionic using your command and the error should not occur again. It worked for me and I hope it will work for you guys. 
Let me know if it was helpful !